# Finding the expected value for this uniform

Tags: probability, self-study

Automobile claim amounts are modeled by a uniform distribution on the interval [0, 
10,000]. Actuary A reports X, the claim amount divided by 1000. Actuary B reports Y, 
which is X rounded to the nearest integer from 0 to 10.
Calculate the absolute value of the difference between the 4th moment of X and the 4th
moment of Y.

Part of Solution:
The Y probabilities are 1/20 for Y = 0 and 10, and 1/10 for Y = 1,2,…,9

Can someone explain with calculations and formulas on how they got "1/20 for Y = 0 and 10, and 1/10 for Y = 1,2,…,9" for this part?

Comment: What $Y$ do you get for values of $X$ between $0$ and $\frac12$? What happens to values of $X$ between $\frac12$ and $1\frac12$?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 3):

$$\Pr(Y=0)=\Pr(X<0.5)=0.5/10=1/20$$
and similarly for the rest of the values of $Y$.